# Most efficient method to separetely print 2 small strings that are binded together

Tags: c

Story : The big string which is `aaa&bbb` is made up of two small strings, what separates the two small strings in the big string is the `&` symbol.

Mission : Print the first and the second small string separately using the most efficient method possible.

Code :

```
char big_str[8] = "aaa&bbb";
```

Desired output :

```
aaa
bbb
```

Comment: You've stated a goal, but not really asked a question. I think perhaps you want to look at `strtok`? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: That's the academic lines that should be in *your* attempt. Now, where is your attempt? And what is your *specific* question concerning that attempt ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is just to use the *field-width* and `'.'` modifiers for the `"%s"` format specifier in `printf` and a couple of pointers, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {

    char big_str[] = "aaa&bbb",
        *p = strchr (big_str, '&'),
        *ep = p + 1;

    if (p)
        printf ("%.*s\n%s\n", (int)(p - big_str), big_str, ep);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/splitand
aaa
bbb
```

**Separating the Values into Separate Strings**

To actually separate the values, you can approach it in the exact same way, except instead of simply printing the output, allocate storage to hold each string and copy the needed characters to each new block of memory. Then you can use the separate strings any way you like, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {

    char big_str[] = "aaa&bbb",
        *p = strchr (big_str, '&'),
        *first, *second;    /* pointers to allocate to hold first/second */

    if (p) {    /* validate '&' located */
        char *ep = p + 1;            /* ep now points to next char after '&' */
        if (!(first = malloc (ep - big_str))) {   /* allocate/validate first */
            perror ("malloc-first");
            return 1;
        }
        memcpy (first, big_str, p - big_str);     /* memcpy to first */
        first[p - big_str] = 0;                   /* nul-terminate */

        if (!(second = malloc (strlen(ep) + 1))) {  /* allocate second */
            perror ("malloc-second");
            return 1;
        }
        strcpy (second, ep);                        /* strcpy is fine here */

        printf ("first  : %s\nsecond : %s\n", first, second);

        free (first);   /* don't forget to free what you allocate */
        free (second);
    }
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/splitanddyn
first  : aaa
second : bbb
```

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Although I perhaps did not ask a very good question, This answer to my question sheds light to the fact that perhaps the location of the `&` should be determined, then the strings can be printed based on the location of the `&` in the big string. If it was not for this answer.. I probably would have gone on to spending time to scan each character at a time and appending them to a buffer until I found the `&` or until the end of the big string was reached.

Comment: Yes, I see you update. You can use a pair of pointers (a start and end pointer) to iterate with `end` to find `'&'` and then the pointer difference `end - start` to determine the number of characters. Or, you can use `strtok()` to do the same thing. I'll drop an update.

Comment: Excellent Answer.

Comment: Thank you for the compliment. I always find it helpful to walk though an example using basic pointers and copies. At least that was the way I found it helpful when I was learning `:)` Once you a comfortable with that, there is nothing you can't parse with a pair of pointers.